# c++ 32 bit tiff image save and load

Tags: c++, image-processing, tiff

Is there any simple implementation to load and save 32 bit tiff images in C++? 
I saw many libraries (e.g., opencv) for image io, but they can't handle 32 bit tiff images.

Comment: is there any 32bit tiff image as an example? So that some test can be done.

Comment: yes, here is an example image: [link](https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B2t2LcQzp4jdWWpjX2RMWFVIVEE&export=download)

Comment: Is that 32-bits because it is 8-bits each of C,M,Y and K? Or 32 bits real/integer integer greyscale?

Comment: The image contains only one channel, that will be 32-bit (the pixels defined by 32-bit float numbers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageMagick can handle 32-bit TIFFs. Using your example image:

```
identify 6.tif 
6.tif TIFF 256x256 256x256+0+0 32-bit Grayscale Gray 262KB 0.000u 0:00.010
```

It can convert your 32-bt TIFF to PNG as well:

```
convert 6.tif a.png
```

Yes, I know I am using the command line, but the C/C++ library is used underneath.

It is available [here](http://www.imagemagick.org) with C/C++, Perl, PHP bindings etc.